# Is the following integral finite? for some values of the exponent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

This is a sequel of the question posted some hours ago: [Is this integral finite? (convergent)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097915/is-this-integral-finite-convergent)

Let us consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and only the region $R=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: \, |x|>1, |y|>1\}$. Is the following integral finite for any value of $\beta>0$?

$$\int_{R} \frac{1}{(\max \{|x|,|y|\})^\beta} dxdy.$$

For $\beta \leq 2$ we saw that it is inifinite by the previous post. But can we now find a suitable power to make it finite? :)

Here is a graph of the integrand for $\beta=4$, it looks convergent but of course I'm not sure. http://www.livephysics.com/tools/mathematical-tools/online-3-d-function-grapher/?xmin=-100&xmax=100&ymin=-100&ymax=100&zmin=Auto&zmax=Auto&f=1%2F%28%28max%28abs%28x%29%2Cabs%28y%29%29%29%5E4%29
Any ideas? :)
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you try to adapt the proof of the answer you accepted for your previous question?

Comment: Sure, but then the latter integral is finite for a suitable $\beta$ so it is not decisive. I even tried to find a direction where the function in the integrand might converge to infinity.. but it is not the case, the function in the integrand vanishes in any direction towards infinity.. so I can't conclude either...

Comment: You should try again: just do the same computations replacing $2$ by $\beta$ and see what's going on.

Comment: I get that for $\beta>2$ the integral is finite, you mean I did something wrong? I computed it two times.. I believe thistime the integral is finite.

Comment: In order to prove convergence for any $\beta > 2$, it is sufficient to (lower-)bound $\max(|x|,|y|)$ in terms of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So we just need to prove that the integral is not convergent for $\beta=2$: the same approch (with an upper bound in terms of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$) works also in that case.

Comment: aha! of course, $max\{|x|,|y|\}\leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ but what kind of upperbound could I get?

Comment: I did not mean anything. But I'm glad that you solved your problem!